If all are Eternally liberated is it against to bramhan or any personal dieties
If all are liberated and consciously experience all Karmas and rebirths knowingly consciously in a liberated manner until they attain final liberation by completely merging into God divine source brahman is this against to bramhan or any personal dieties

I think it is not against to God because the scenario which I describe in that scenario sufferings are reduced and minimised I think there is no change in Brahman or any personal dieties I think this will not go against to them
